# Removing Time Stamp With Sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have found a couple examples online.. but I could not 
find a combination that would work, as the synx for sed 
is very tricky, if you could please kindly point me in
right direction I would be highly grateful..

Here is the time stamp that i would like to remove from the file

00:02:06.580 --> 00:02:07.380

Here is what i already tried

```
cat sometextfile.txt | sed -r 's /\[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\/ g'
```

But I keep getting and error: sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated `s' command

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `s/` *what to replace* `/` *what to replace it with* `/`.  You are missing the second part.  Even if you want to replace it with nothing, you need all three slashes; just don't put anything between the last two. As it is, you have only one slash, because the second one is quoted with `\`, meaning `sed` will treat it as part of the expression and look for a literal `/` in the input.

The beginning of your regex is also wrong.  `\[0-9]{2}` matches the literal string `[0-9` followed by exactly two right brackets (`]]`). Remove the initial backslash (`\`) if you want to match "exactly two digits".

Also, you never need to do `cat` *filename* `|`; you can just do `<` *filename*.  In this specific case, `sed` takes a filename parameter, so you can do without the `<`, too.

So it should be something like this;

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}//' sometextfile.txt
```

(I used `-E` because it's more portable than `-r`, which is a GNUism.)

You don't need the `g` on the end unless there's more than one timestamp per line.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. I was able to remove about half of the string with the suggested command.. This should be enough to get me started, thanks again!!

Comment: cat file.txt | sed -E 's/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-999]{3}//g' > file_nostring.txt

Comment: Not that it's likely that anything else would match your pattern, but be aware that `.` matches *any* character. To match a literal decimal point/period, use `\.`.